# Creating a Collection that can be edited in modules

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to create a discord game bot.

Im trying to make a collection which stores the user's id as the key and its bank balance as the value. But it is not working for some reason. I'm not sure why,

This is main.js

```
.....
const userValues = new Discord.Collection();
.....
client.on('message', message => {

    var userid = message.author.id;
    var messager = userValues.find(userid);
    
    if (messager === false){
        userValues.set(userid, 0);
    };

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    if(command === 'explore'){
       client.commands.get('explore').execute(message, args, userValues);
       }
});
```

This is in explore.js

```
var currentBalance = userValues.get(userid);
        userValues.set(userid, currentBalance + coins);
        message.reply("\n" + 'You searched a ' + choice + ' and found $' + coins);
```

Comment: "But it is not working for some reason. I'm not sure why," -> Please specify your intended behavior as well as what the current behavior is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a major problem I see in your code. Apart from that, there may be more issues in your code, but I will address the main issue as I cannot tell if the other potential issues are actual problems with just the code you've provided.

You are doing `userValues.find("a key")` which is an incorrect use of the `.find()` method. `.find()` is meant to find elements in the Collection based on the items' properties (if the item is an object). But in your Collection, the items (values) themselves are integers as they represent the balance of your users. You could use either `.get("a key")` or `.has("a key")` to properly check if the key is in the `Collection`, but I will use `.has()` since that is what it is intended to do.

What you probably should do:

```
const userValues = new Discord.Collection();
.....
client.on('message', message => {

    var userid = message.author.id;
    
    if (!userValues.has(userid)){
        //Do this if userValues DOESN'T contain the user's ID and balance
        userValues.set(userid, 0);
    }

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    if(command === 'explore'){
       client.commands.get('explore').execute(message, args, userValues);
    }
});
```

I would recommend being more descriptive in your questions than simply saying "it isn't working". How is it not working, what do you mean by "not working"? Is it giving an error? Is it keeping the balance at `0` for every user? Without such important information, how would we even know what problem you are experiencing?

Relevant resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=has

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying to solve it for 3 hours now.
I was wondering that does executing userValues in client.commands.get().execute() and in the execute() in the actual file is enough to be able to edit it or use it in other modules?